# How to upload an email attachment file in WooCommerce Orders of WordPress Admin Panel

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Is it possible to upload an email attachment file (e.g., PDF quote) right in the WooCommerce>Orders section?

I want WooCommerce attach the file to the default email template when I hit update button to complete and order.

I do not want to put the file(s) on server.

Answer (score 0):

this code will let you add a static PDF file (or in fact, any kind of file) to the WooCommerce Order Emails.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email', 10, 3);

function attach_terms_conditions_pdf_to_email ( $attachments , $id, $object ) {
$your_pdf_path = get_template_directory() . '/terms.pdf';
$attachments[] = $your_pdf_path;
return $attachments;
}
// you need to upload your term in your upload directory
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mostafa. Your suggestion does attach the file. However I am wondering is there any way to read the $your_pdf_path from an open file dialog box opens in WooCommerce Orders?